# IMPORTHTML/XML Table in Google Sheets returns only 50 values

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I own a game store and we are attempting to use PriceCharting to update large quantities of trading cards efficiently.

I've attempted to import large quantities of trading cards, around 100-200, organized by "Set", into a Google Sheet using IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML; however, we're hitting a limit of 50 values being pulled by either of these functions.

Example functions:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.pricecharting.com/console/pokemon-japanese-151?sort=model-number&model-number=&exclude-variants=true", "//td[@class='price numeric used_price']")
```

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.pricecharting.com/console/pokemon-japanese-151?sort=model-number&model-number=&exclude-variants=true", "table", 1)
```

Based on my searches on StackOverflow, it seems that Google Sheets imposes a limit of 50 results for both of these functions; so my question is how this can be circumvented. Is there another function we can use to pull up to 300 results from one page, is there a way we can pull result 1-50 on one page, 51-100 on another page, and concatenate them together in one sheet? Etc.

All help is appreciated! I'm a novice so I've done my best but even after hours of searching I feel like I've hit a wall.